# 502 Bad Gateway when using alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-load-balancer-controller

We have a kubernetes cluster on aws eks, using the aws load balancer controller to manage albs using k8s ingress. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller

When using the following annotation `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS` aws alb is not able to communicate with our kubernetes service.

**curl -i https://example-api-2.acme-test.com/ping**

```
HTTP/2 502 server: awselb/2.0 date: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 08:47:21 GMT content-type: text/html content-length: 122
    
<html> <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head> <body> <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center> </body> </html>
```

However changing `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS` from`HTTPS` to `HTTP` resolves this issue, and we are able to communicate with the service using the same curl command..

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example 
  namespace: example 
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "acme-test"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <redacted>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /health
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '300'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
      #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: example-api.<redacted>.om
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-api-2
                port:
                  number: 80
```

**Environment**

- AWS Load Balancer controller version: 2.5
- Kubernetes version: 1.2.6
- Using EKS (yes/no), if so version? yes

We have this same configuration working (`HTTPS`) on an older version K8s EKS ( 1.2.2) AWS Controller version 2.4.1.

[image]

**kubectl get all -n example**

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/example-api-2-cd6cdd88f-5df5n   1/1     Running   0          15h

NAME                    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/example-api-2   NodePort   172.20.37.178   <none>        80:30451/TCP   20h

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/example-api-2   1/1     1            1           20h

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/example-api-2-cd6cdd88f    1         1         1       15h
```

**kubectl describe service example-api-2 -n example**

```
Name:                     example-api-2
Namespace:                example
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=example-api-2
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       172.20.37.178
IPs:                      172.20.37.178
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30451/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.6.119:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

**kubectl describe deployment example-api-2 -n example**

```
Name:                   example-api-2
Namespace:              example
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 17 Apr 2023 12:40:06 +0100
Labels:                 app=example-api-2
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 5
Selector:               app=example-api-2
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=example-api-2
           log-label=true
           log-namespace=acme
  Containers:
   example-api-2:
    Image:      <redacted>.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/example-api:v0.4.7-2api
    Port:       80/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
false
      ENVIRONMENT:                production
    Mounts:                       <none>
  Volumes:                        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   example-api-2-cd6cdd88f (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. Have you considered posting this in the LB controller repository? Also, make sure the VPC CNI is at 1.12 or higher. You can try tracing the traffic with [ksniff](https://github.com/eldadru/ksniff) or tcpdump too.